# Dict value to int python

Tags: python, dictionary

how can i change the dict values which digit to int and have no quotes

User input this string

```
{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}
```

what ive tried

```
t=[x for x in input()[2:-1].split(", ")]
w=[]
for i in t:
    a=i
    e=a.replace("'","").replace('"','').split(":")
    w.append(e)
for i in w:
    for j in i:
        if j.isdigit():
            j=int(j)
d=[tuple(x) for x in w]
print(d)
```

It shows that 30 type int but it has quotes

Output

```
[('name', 'John'), ('age', '30'), ('city', 'New York')]
```

I want 30 to be without quotes

```
[('name', 'John'), ('age', 30), ('city', 'New York')]
```

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to start by parsing the string with `ast.literal_eval` and then get its items.

Comment: Why do you have to go through all of that code? all you have to do is `list(mydict.items())` simpler

Comment: @khelwood im beginner and i would like to use more simple things

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna  its not dict at beginnig its a string

Comment: oh, the user inputs a string :')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna i dont know almost every task like that for us user inputs smt

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna my bad i shoudve add to question no imports for beginner who doesnt know imports

Comment: All you need to do is change the type of the `30` to `int` when you're making the list of  tuples(first `for` loop).
`for i in t:
    a=i
    e=a.replace("'","").replace('"','').split(":")
    if e[0] == 'age':    # <- here
        e[1] = int(e[1])
    w.append(e)` . sorry the question is closed :)

Answer (score 1):

Given this string

```
string = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
```

Parse it to a dict with

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(string)
```

then get its items

```
print(list(data.items()))

[('name', 'John'), ('age', 30), ('city', 'New York')]
```

Comment: isnt there basic ways without all this import staff and libr?

Comment: It doesn't get any more basic than this. `ast` is module from Pythons standard library and if it provides you with a simple solution you should use it and not try to invent the wheel yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is JSON

```
import json

spam = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
eggs = json.loads(spam)
print(eggs)
print(eggs['age'])
```

output:

```
{'name': 'John', 'age': 30, 'city': 'New York'}
30
```

Comment: i kinda know that with json but in this case Its USER INPUT {"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}

Comment: So, store the user input in a variable and use it. What is the problem? I just hard-code the user input for the code example.

Comment: i think u right but i just want to be able to do it without some imports